# Make the numbers in the enumerate environments links

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, links

I am making a list, and I would like the numbers of the items of this list to be some links (not labels) for some other part in the text.

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}


\begin{theorem}
    theorem 2 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq:  1}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
    
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    theorem 2 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq:  2}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
    
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
    theorem 2 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq:  3}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
    
\end{theorem}

Here there is a list with all the limits: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} = 1$ \textbf{Here i want to click on the item to go to equation 3, labeled eq:  3}
    \item $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 $
    \item $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} = 1 $
\end{enumerate}

\textcolor{blue}{I want to click on the \textbf{numbers} in the enumerate environment to go to the link of formulas in theorems.}  





\end{document}
```

[image: I want to click on the numbers to go to the equations]

By clicking on the numbers (in the picture the ones in the blue circles), you should go to the equation.

Comment: Should the numbers of the items be the number of the equation or should it just count as usual but the number should link to the equation?

Comment: the second one, the enumerate should count as usual but the numbers should link to the equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach that defines a new command `\linkitem` that creates an `\item` with a custom label, i.e., `\item[xx]`. In this custom label the link is created using `\hyperref[label]{link text}`.

The link text consists of the enumerate counter `enumi`, printed using `\theenumi`, and a dot. Because custom labels do not increase the counter (i.e., `\item[xx]` followed by a regular `\item` creates item labels `xx` for the first and `1` for the second item) the counter is increased manually with `\stepcounter{enumi}` beforehand.

One remaining issue is that `\item[\hyperref{...}]` does not work because for some reason the item label is stored as a pdf string (probably in case the item itself is referenced at some point). You can set a separate pdf string without a link using `\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[label]{text}}{text}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\linkitem}[1]{%
\stepcounter{enumi}%
\item[\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[#1]{\theenumi.}}{\theenumi.}]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    theorem 1 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq1}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    theorem 2 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq2}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    theorem 3 is 
    \begin{align}
    \label{eq3}
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} = 1
    \end{align}
\end{theorem}

Here there is a list with all the limits: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \linkitem{eq3} $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{x} -1}{x} = 1$ \textbf{Here i want to click on the item to go to equation 3, labeled eq1}
    \linkitem{eq1} $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$
    \item regular item
    \linkitem{eq2} $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$
\end{enumerate}
\textcolor{blue}{I want to click on the \textbf{numbers} in the enumerate environment to go to the link of formulas in theorems.}  
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! It works